# What are the differences between Solr 3.6.2 and Solr 4.0?

Tags: solr

Are there any major differences between Solr 3.6 and Solr 4.0 other than new features? Am I safe using my existing queries (those that work in Solr 3.6) inside of Solr 4.0?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Are there any major differences between Solr 3.6 and Solr 4.0 other
>   than new features?

I find this question weird, least to say. Bug fixes and new features **are** the whole point of releases!

You can look at the full changelog of the Solr release which is a available [here](http://lucene.apache.org/solr/4_0_0/changes/Changes.html). Don't forget that Solr and [Lucene](http://lucene.apache.org/)  are released in unison so you also need to look for relevant changes in both projects.

> Am I safe using my existing queries (those that work in Solr 3.6)
>   inside of Solr 4.0?

Queries should be fine, but indices - probably not. Quoting javanna from [another SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13009928/migrate-data-from-solr-3):

> The index format has changed, but Solr will take care of upgrading the
>   index. That happens automatically once you start Solr with your old
>   index. But after that the index cannot be read anymore by a previous
>   Solr/lucene version.

Answer (score 0):

Ideally they should work.
You can probably check the [Changes.txt](http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/lucene/dev/tags/lucene_solr_4_0_0_BETA/solr/CHANGES.txt) which would give an idea of all the new features, Changes, Bug fixes, Optimization done.
If any things breaks, you can always refer to the Changes to check if any related has been changed.